# After Getting an HashSet from a Map and changing it, do i have to put it back?

Tags: java, dictionary, pass-by-reference

It works like this:

```
Set<Integer> nums = numMap.get(id);
nums.add(new Integer(0));
// now do i have to:
numMap.put(id,nums)?
// or is it already stored?
```

regards && tia 
   noircc

Comment: `numMap.put(nums)` doesn't make sense. Where's the key?

Comment: my bad, should be numMap.put(id,nums)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to put it back, unless you make a deep clone of it. Everything works based on references in Java.

You can always test this by writing a simple program.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> numMap = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.add(10);

    numMap.put(0, set);

    System.out.println("Map before adding is " + numMap);

    set.add(20);

    System.out.println("Map after adding is " + numMap);
}
```

Which prints

```
Map before adding is {0=[10]}
Map after adding is {0=[20, 10]}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to re-insert it.

The `numMap` stores *references* to the values, and the `Set`s reference doesn't change just because you change the content of the Set.

You *would* have to reinsert it if you used the `Set` as a *key* in the hash map, since changing the content of the Set, changes the Set's hash code.

```
Map<Set<Integer>, String> map = new HashSet<Set<Integer>, String>();

Set<Integer> nums = ...
map.put(nums, "Hello");    // Use a Set<Integer> as *key*.

nums.add(new Integer(0));  // This changes the keys hashCode (not allowed)

// now do i have to:
numMap.put(nums)?
```

You would need to remove the mapping before changing the key, and reinsert the mapping after changing the key.